# How to delete font on iOS?

Tags: ios, font, customization

Is there a way to uninstall font on iOS?

I played with fonts on my iPhone and installed some with help of apps. But now I need to remove them for developing purposes.

Comment: To my knowledge, you can't install fonts on iOS. If you mean keyboards, you can remove them in settings (Settings -> General -> Keyboard -> Keyboards -> Press Edit and remove the keyboards you don't want). If you did install Fonts, which app did you use? And why do you need to remove them?

Comment: @Luke35, any custom font, provided by the app becomes available in all other apps. In my case I used this demo app: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/DownloadFont/Introduction/Intro.html. I want to clean up my iphone because those fonts appear in other text-editing apps.